# Android SDK's AVD does not load the Emulator at all

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm unable to start the emulator. I can create new devices in the AVD, they appear with a little green tick next to the name, but they do not start. No emulator loads up. No error message shows up either. I've tried waiting for over 15 minutes.
The same happens when I try to load it up on eclipse. I have a test project. It compiles & tries to launch, I get the message below on the console after which nothing happens.

```
[2012-05-13 15:26:30 - TestApp] ------------------------------
[2012-05-13 15:26:30 - TestApp] Android Launch!
[2012-05-13 15:26:30 - TestApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-05-13 15:26:30 - TestApp] Performing com.test.testapp.TestAppActivity activity launch
[2012-05-13 15:26:30 - TestApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MyAVD'
[2012-05-13 15:26:30 - TestApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MyAVD'
```

Weird thing is, it used to work before I had formatted & re-installed Windows.
I don't know where I'm going wrong; I've tried searching on Google & StackOverflow to find a solution & I've tried all the solutions I found with no success.

Class Path is set. SDK installed to a location with no spaces in the path. Restarted. Re-Installed. Changed "Launch Default Activity", "Automatic Target" to "Manual". No luck. There is no running Android Device. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Details:

64 Bit Windows

32 Bit JDK

32 Bit Java EE Eclipse Extracted to "C:\eclipse"

Android SDK Installed to "C:\android-sdk"

PATH variable includes:

";C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin"

";C:\android-sdk\platform-tools"

";C:\android-sdk\tools"

Comment: Assuming your computer's ram size is low (even 4GB is low sometimes). Did you tried decreasing avd ram size to something low as 256 mb?

Comment: Yeah, just tried that. Same result! :(

Comment: Alright, the problem basically "solved" itself after I had formatted & re-installed Windows along with the Android SDK + eclipse.

Comment: I would not called that solved. I cannot afford to reinstall everything if something stops working. A casuse and solution is needed.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, and I would really despise having to reinstall everything.

Comment: Anderson, I know it isn't really solved, hence the double quotes. I have nothing new to contribute as to what caused the issue, nor do I know how to fix it.

dudewad, although I'm not a 100% sure of this; what I did the after the format was install a 64 bit JDK. Maybe try that before having to resort to anything drastic.